# Java scanner with integer validation

Tags: java

What is the correct syntax to get Integers from scanner if they meet some criteria and assign to arrayList? It should loop and get the inputs until we insert "-1".
It stops then I insert "q" but I need it to work with certain integer.

```
              Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
              while (-99 !== sc.nextLine() && sc.hasNextInt()) 
              {
              //do something Whi
              }
```

Comment: How can a Scanner Object be equals to a negative `int` ?

Comment: input from a scannershould be

Comment: Then please show me how to do it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop until -1 is encountered, and add the elements to the arraylist.
Let me know if you need any help in this.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// keep looping until -1 is encountered
while (true) {
        int temp = scanner.nextInt();
        if (temp == -1) {
            break;
        }
        list.add(temp);
}

// Printing the array list
System.out.println(list);

// closing the scanner is important
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what your requirements are but how about

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) 
{
    int numEntered = sc.nextInt ();
    if (numEntered  == -1) {
        break;
    }
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood what i was doing wrong! This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;
do{
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()){
        sc.next();
    }
    num = sc.nextInt();
}while(num!=-1)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

sc if a refrence to a object of Scanner class and not compaire with int object. you must check the value of next int in your while loop